# Расширение для VISUAL STUDIO, которое подкрашивает ключевые слова запросов

Tags: sql, visual-studio, плагин

Запросы находятся в ресурсах в виде *.sql файлов, а в месте вызова находятся инструкции такого вида:

```
Properties.Resources.Query
```

При наведении курсора на Query высвечивается текст запроса, но подсветки синтаксиса нет.

Есть ли какие-нибудь плагины, которые исправляют данную проблему?

Можно конечно открывать файлы в обозреватели VS и там все подсвечивается, но это не всегда удобно, так как плодятся лишние вкладки.

Comment: http://www.codinion.com/ подсветка для 2015 студии, насчет запросов не  уверен, нужно смотреть

Comment: http://savepic.ru/12761556.htm классы подкрашивает

Comment: @user2455111,не, запросы не подкрашивает.

Answer (score 1):

Такой вопрос уже [обсуждался](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023881/is-it-possible-to-syntax-highlight-in-line-sql) на англоязычном SO, и в качестве варианта было предложено вот [это](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fbdegroot.SQLSyntaxHighlighting) расширение для Visual Studio 2012, которое путём редактирования манифеста можно попробовать завести и в более новых версиях Visual Studio. Однако, обсуждение сошлось на том, что работать это не может корректно, так как синтаксический анализатор не в состоянии определить, является ли строка SQL кодом или просто строкой и может работать некорректно.

В качестве альтернативы, можно использовать .sql-файлы с кодом SQL в проекте (которые в принципе подсвечиваются довольно неплохо), используя их так:

```
 string sql = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("путь к файлу .sql");
```

Все ответы взяты из [оригинального англоязычного обсуждения](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023881/is-it-possible-to-syntax-highlight-in-line-sql).

Answer (score 1):

Как по мне то [Syntax Highlighting Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.SyntaxHighlightingPack) подходит наилучше, потому что поддерживает очень много языков программирования и работает с Visual Studio 2015, 2017